# Including <experimental/coroutine> in MinGW-w64 v13.2.0 with g++ and C++17 on Windows 11

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm facing an issue on Windows11 with MinGW-w64 version 13.2.0 while compiling a C++ file using g++. When I compile the file with the -std=c++17 flag, I receive a fatal error indicating that the <experimental/coroutine> header file is missing. The exact error message is as follows:

```
fatal error: experimental/coroutine: No such file or directory
   56 | #include <experimental/coroutine>
```

How can I successfully include the coroutine header in this setup?

I tried adding -fcoroutines to the command line arguments, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Additionally, I found a file named coroutine in the MinGW-w64 directory at .\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\13.2.0\include\c++\coroutine. Is this file related to the problem I'm experiencing?

Comment: It's no longer experimental, just `#include <coroutine>`.

Comment: And don't forget to switch to C++20 to use `<coroutine>`.

Comment: `#include <experimental/coroutine>` in question is from the code within the Windows SDK's C++/WinRT. I've learned that the latest version of C++/WinRT is written in C++17, so I would prefer to compile without altering that specific portion of the code, if possible.

I usually use MinGW-w64 for writing C++ on Windows, so I would like to find a solution that works with it if possible. However, I am open to considering other compilers if they can handle this situation better.